# ios - NSString URL decode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, urldecode

I'm trying to Decode URL,but i'm getting warning message like "NSString may not respond to URLDecode".

```
NSString* token = [[urlStr substringFromIndex:r.location + 1] URLDecode];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is URLDecode function ?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information showing what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: replace URLDecode with URLDecodedString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is not a method a classic NSString respond to, you can though add a category like the following, to add the method yourself :

```
@interface NSString (URLDecode)
- (NSString *)URLDecode;
@end

@implementation NSString
- (NSString *)URLDecode
{
    NSString *result = [(NSString *)self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
    result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}
@end
```

Comment: I wrote a similar category but ran in to an issue when I tried to decode a string @"abcjhjhdfjhafjakhfjaklfj12346890(*^$#@@@#$%^^     ........", it this method returns nil. It looks like stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is causing some problems because of "Returns nil if the transformation is not possible (i.e. the percent escapes give a byte sequence not legal in the given encoding). " (from NSURL.h). So just a heads up for those that ran into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
NSString* urlEncoded = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744

it may help you.